# How to search and cut strings from a file?

Tags: command-line, bash, text-processing, sed, awk

I'm trying to write a program with options and arguments like that:

```
./program.sh -f <filename> -string <string>
```

The program is supposed to output the line of `<filename>` which begins with `<string>` like so:

```
 grep ^<string> <filename>
```

Plus it's supposed to return some information associated with the string, like name and age in the following example input file:

```
string name age sex
Akdk john 22 male
Jrtkfp miah 26 female
```

How can I achieve a behaviour like that?

Comment: It seems that you've asked that already. The question is was unclear. Instead of editing the question, you asked it again. It is still unclear.

Comment: Damn your was a lot better i didnt see it thank you so much

Comment: Well i dont want people to write me the program it feels like cheating :p

Comment: I guess something like that might help

Comment: Provide a bit more context of what you are trying to do and in what language.  Programming questions are not specifically off topic but there are better sites than this for programming questions.  I doubt anyone will just give you the solution but we may be able to put you in the right direction even if that means migrating this question to another stackexchange site.

Answer (score 6):

An operation as simple as this can be done with a oneliner, you don't need a whole script for that. I'd go with a function which you can put in your `~/.bash_aliases` file so that it's loaded in every terminal you open.

```
function_name(){ awk /^$2/'{print $1": "$2", "$3}' $1 ;}
```

This allows you to call `function_name <filename> <string>` and get the result as shown below:

```
$ cat test
string name age sex
Akdk john 22 male
Jrtkfp miah 26 female

$ function_name test Akdk
Akdk: john, 22
```

As you can see, you can achieve this goal without any options, using only arguments is much simpler. If you somehow need options I recommend [this tutorial](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/howto/getopts_tutorial) and [this article](http://aplawrence.com/Unix/getopts.html).

#### Explanations

- `function_name(){ … ;}` – defines the function `function_name` which does `…`
- `awk /^$2/'{…}' $1` – in the file given as the first argument to the function (`$1`) search for the lines which begins (`^`) with the second argument (`$2`) to the function and do `…` with it
- `awk '{print $1": "$2", "$3}'` – print the first column (space separated), then “: ”, then the second column, then “, ” and then the third column

NB: E.g. `$1` has a different meaning for `bash` (what runs your terminal) as for `awk`: The first expands it to the first argument you gave it, the second interprets it as a shortcut for the first column. That's why we need single quotes (`'`) around `awk`'s `print` command, that way `bash` doesn't expand `$1` but lets it untouched for `awk` to parse.